# applying awk on multiply folder and subfiles

Tags: awk

I have 10 folders with consecutives name : book_1, book_2..... book_10 and each folder has a txt file named same as the folder. For example : book_1 has *only* book_1.txt and contains history material (only text).

I need to run an AWK script which output should be added by order to the output file.
How can I generate a loop which runs through my folders and extractes the needed file from each folder?

```
awk '
    {
        script//
    }
    END { print "The output of book num $i is:  " m }' book*/book*.txt >> output.txt // m is a variable which extracts max occurences of certain words which are set in the script
```

My output should look like this:

```
The output of book num 1 is : 123
The output of book num 2 is : 2223
```

and so on

thank you for your help!

Comment: Awk is a mighty tool for text transformation, not for handling files. You are looking for a combination of `find` and `cat`. Hint: There a dozens of simple ways to achieve it.

Comment: Please show the contents of at least one example file `book_1/book_1.txt` (or better two files) in your question and explain where the numbers `123` and `2223` come from if it's not obvious.

Comment: Added some description. Each book has some reading material in different subject. the output displays max occurences of certain words

Comment: `awk` doesn't really know how to open directories. The solution to your problem may be just to call it with the right arguments, eg. `awk '...' book_?/book_?.txt book_??/book_??.txt` which will rely on the shell globbing to expand the file arguments in the right order.

Comment: Within awk, you can check if it's the beginning of a new file with `FILENAME==fn { fn = FILENAME; ... }` or via the `FNR` variable. GNU awk also has `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` similar to `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: what is the syntex for calling directories?  what should appear insted of '?'? and can I just list file names one after the other  ?

Comment: I don't get what "syntax for calling directories" mean. Your glob pattern `book_*/book_*.txt` will expand the filenames in the WRONG order, ie. `book_10/book_10.txt` before `book_2/book_2.txt`. Thence my suggestion to use `book_?/book_?.txt book_??/book_??.txt`, and to use the `FILENAME` var to determine when a new filename has started.

Comment: @mosvy As I wrote before - I think it's best to forget about awk for this task at all.

Comment: @rexkogitans per the posted example script `m is a variable which extracts max occurences of certain words which are set in the script` which sounds like a pretty reasonable job for awk to perform on the files that are found, the only real question is how to find/process the files in the desired order.

Comment: @rexkogitans I'm no mind reader, and I don't know what the mysterious `//script` from the OP does. But assuming that it does a simple task like "calculate the average word count / line", here is challenge for you: "Forget about awk", and do this with a "combination of find and cat": `awk 'function show(){if(fn)printf "%s\t%g\n", fn, nf/nr} FILENAME!=fn{show();fn=FILENAME;nf=nr=0} {nf+=NF;nr++} END{show()}' book_?/book_?.txt book_??/book_??.txt book_???/book_???.txt`

Comment: Thank you all for your input, unfortunately I couldn't add my script but still I appreciate your help @mosby

Comment: Yes, you CAN add your script. Simply create a small script that demonstrates your specific problem (i.e. visiting files in a specific order) and [edit] your question to show that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way using any awk in a shell that supports the `{1..10}` construct for generating a range of numbers (otherwise just use `$(seq 10)`) is:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    awk -v i="$i" '
        {
            script//
        }
        END { printf "The output of book num %d is : %d\n", i, m }
    ' "book_${i}/book_${i}.txt"
done > output.txt
```

but if you really wanted to do it all in awk it'd be (using GNU awk for ARGIND and ENDFILE):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            ARGV[ARGC] = "book_" i "/book_" i ".txt"
            ARGC++
        }
    }
    {
        script//
    }
    ENDFILE { printf "The output of book num %d is : %d\n", ARGIND, m; m=0 }
'  > output.txt
```

If any of the "book" files can not exist then you'd need to add some protection against that.

Comment: I used your first script, and it almost did the job. however for some reason the output numbering was out of order and didn't include all of the numbers in the range (I tried using both methods {1..10} and $(seq 10) but got same result. Only the the number order is oncorrect, the output by itself corresponds to it's true number (by line count). For example : 
The output of book num 4 is 123 // output matches book 1
The output of book num 1 is 234 //output matches book 2
The output of book num 4 is 333 //output matches book 3

Comment: I can't imagine how `{1..10}` or `seq 10` could produce output that's not the numbers 1 through 10 in that order. You must not be doing **exactly** what I show in my script. Please edit your question to show a complete, minimal script that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I looked through my script again and found a variable named "i" which led to false indexing. Again thank you!